# loading/processing animation in perl

Tags: perl

Is there a way to display an animation while Perl is processing a file or something else?
Maybe the sequence of `| / - | \` (rotating pipe) instead of just printing dots.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple rotating pipe can be created using code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$|++; # turn off output buffering;

my @chars = qw(| / - \ );

my $i = 0;

print $chars[$i];

while (1) {
  sleep 1;
  print "\b", $chars[++$i % @chars];
}
```

For something more complex, take a look at [Term::ProgressBar](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-ProgressBar/).

Comment: Thanks, I was trying Win32::Console, but "\b" looks better.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, something like this will do it:

```
perl -e '$|++; foreach $i (0..10) { print "\r", substr("|/-\\", ($i % 4), 1); sleep 1; }'
```

You can put code like this inside your processing loop to display an appropriate spinner.